# Android application on Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Is there anyway to run Android application in windows phone (Windows 8.1 denim version).
I was trying to use a application that was developed in android platform and i didn't succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

With Windows (Mobile) 10 it will be possible to convert Android and iOS apps into WP apps that can run on the Windows Mobile OS. But for Windows Phone 8.1 there is no possibility so far.

http://www.theverge.com/2015/4/29/8511439/microsoft-windows-10-android-ios-apps-bridges